# hide cursor in mouse move handler and show it on mouse up

Tags: event-handling, cursor, hide, show

I'm developing a schematic editor, i need to hide the cursor when the middle key is down and moving, and show it again when the mouse up event occurs to implement an user friendly zooming system. The hide and show methods works fine when they are called from outside these event handlers, bud does not work when then called within the event handler!